# Azure Blob Destination in SSIS - blob name as expression

Tags: azure-blob-storage, ssis-2019

I'm attempting to pass the blob name as variable in SSIS Azure Blob Destination.  I use expressions all the time in SSIS but cannot find the "Expressions" option in the [Azure Blob Destination] data flow component properties.

Answer (score 3):

I found the expressions for the [Azure Blob Destination] data flow component.  It's in the properties of the [Data Flow] task on the Control Flow tab.

I'm used to accessing the expressions of the [Flat File Destination] connection so I was hunting on the Data Flow tab.